# How does this diode improve the common mode conducted noise?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, noise, emc

This image was taken from [UCC28881 (page 16)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc28881.pdf)

[image]

The desciption in the body says:

> A half-wave rectifier is chosen and implemented by diode D2 (1N4937). It is a general purpose 1-A, 600-V
>   rated diode. It has a fast reverse recovery time (200 ns) for improved differential-mode-conducted EMI noise
>   performance. **Diode D3 (1N4007) is a general purpose 1-A, 1-kV rated diode with standard reverse recovery
>   time (>500 ns), and is added for improved common-mode-conducted EMI noise performance.** D3 can be
>   removed and replaced by a short if not needed.

My question is how does D3 improve the EMI noise performance ?

Comment: common mode noise flows in the same direction down both wires, the diodes ensure that such a thing can't happen, thus limiting you to differential noise only (which can sometimes be easier to filter)

Comment: @Sam ah. That makes sense.